# Intuition behind working with `k` to find the kth-symbol in the grammar

Tags: c++, algorithm

I took part in a [coding contest](https://discuss.leetcode.com/category/1757/weekly-contest-70) wherein I encountered the following question:

> On the first row, we write a 0. Now in every subsequent row, we look at the previous row and replace each occurrence of 0 with 01, and each occurrence of 1 with 10.  Given row N and index K, return the K-th indexed symbol in row N. (The values of K are 1-indexed.)

While solving the question, [I solved it](https://www.ideone.com/rbiGAw) like a level-order traversal of a tree, trying to form the new string at each level.  Unfortunately, it timed-out.  I then tried to think along the terms of caching the results, etc. with no luck.

One of the [highly upvoted solutions](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/119462/my-3-lines-c-recursive-solution) is like this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int kthGrammar(int N, int K) {
    if (N == 1) return 0;
    if (K % 2 == 0) return (kthGrammar(N - 1, K / 2) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    else return (kthGrammar(N - 1, (K + 1) / 2) == 0) ? 0 : 1;
    }
};
```

My question is simple - what is the intuition behind working with the value of `K` (especially, the parities of `K`)?  (I hope to be able to identify such questions when I encounter them in future).

Thanks.

Comment: If you write out the first five or six rows, you'll notice a pattern. Then, walk through the above algorithm by hand. You'll see how the algorithm takes advantage of that pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the sequence recursively.  In generating a new row, the first half is identical to the process you used to get the previous row, so that part of the expansion is already done.  The second half is merely the same sequence inverted (0 for 1, 1 for 0).  This is one classic way to generate a parity map: flip all the bits and append, representing adding a `1` to the start of each binary number.  Thinking of expanding the sequence 0-3 to 0-7, we start with

```
00 => 0
01 => 1
10 => 1
11 => 0
```

We now replicate the 2-digit sequence twice: first with a leading 0, which preserves the original parity; second with a leading 1, which inverts the parity.

```
000 => 0
001 => 1
010 => 1
011 => 0
100 => 1
101 => 0
110 => 0
111 => 1
```

Is that an intuition that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

The check for parity in the code you posted is just to make the division by two correct, there's no advanced math or mystery hiding here :) Since the pattern is akin to a tree, where the pattern size multiplies by two for each added row, correctly dividing points to the element's parent. The indexes in this question are said to be "1-indexed;" if the index is 2, dividing by two yields the parent index (1) in the row before; and if the index is 1, dividing (1+1) by two yields that same parent index. I'll leave it to the reader to generalize that to `k`s parity. After finding the parent, the code follows the rule stated in the question: if the parent is 0, the left-child must be 0 and right-child 1, and vice versa.

```
               0
       0               1
   0       1       1       0
 0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0

      a    a   b    a   b   b   a
0 01 0110 01101001 0110100110010110

 a   b   b   a    b   a   a   b
0110100110010110 1001011001101001
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, as a different way to solve this, consider that the `n`th row (0-indexed) has `2^n` elements in it, and a determination as to the value of the `k`th (0-indexed) element can be made soley according to the parity of how many bits are set in `k`.